# display a input according to the selected value in a drop-down list Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to show an input once the "maintenance" (manutenção in br) option is selected in the dropdown, what is wrong?  I think I'm on the right path but there's something that's not right...

html:

```
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 mt-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Status</label>
      <p-dropdown
        [filter]="true"
        [options]="installationDeviceStatus"
        [(ngModel)]="labelSelected"
        [style]="{ width: '100%' }"
        autoWidth="false"
        formControlName="installation"
      ></p-dropdown>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div
    class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 mt-2"
    *ngIf="labelSelected == 'Operacao'"
  >
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Motivo da Operacao</label>
      <input
        class="form-control"
        formControlName="operancao"
        readonlyDisable
        type="text"
        placeholder="Digite aqui o motivo"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
```

ts:

```
  public installationDeviceStatus = [
    {
      label: "",
      value: "",
    },
    {
      label: "",
      value: "",
    },
    {
      label: "",
      value: "",
    },
    {
      label: "",
      value: "",
    }
  ];
  labelSelected: string = "";
```

Comment: Your `labelSelected` has to be of the same type as `installationDeviceStatus` items, it cannot be just string. Something like: `installationDeviceStatus: SomeType[]` and `labelSelected: SomeType`. So, when it's of the same type, you can change `*ngIf="labelSelected == 'Manutenção'"` to `*ngIf="labelSelected.label == 'Manutenção'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should access obj `labelSelected` propery e.g `label` to compare with string `Manutenção`. Right now your trying to compare if obj `{}` equals `Manutenção` (no it does not).

```html
  <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 mt-2"
    *ngIf="labelSelected.label === 'Manutenção'" >
```

Answer (score 0):

labelSelected need to be an object, like this

```
labelSelected:any={
label: "Manutenção",
value: "manutencao"
}
```

and the if condition to show div you should be like this

```
  <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 mt-2" *ngIf="labelSelected.label == 'Manutenção'" >
```